# PHP exec("sudo ...") doesn't seem to work when called over the web?

Tags: php, permissions, apache2

I have a script `write_get.php` that I would like to execute via users remotely loading a web page. This script in turn runs

```
exec("sudo php save_file.php ".$arg1)
```

to do some file writing that requires `sudo` permissions. This works fine when I run `write_get.php` from the command line on my web server as a non-privileged user, but it doesn't work fine when I invoke the script by loading it in a web browser. The web browser presents the same message, making it appear as though there is no error, but the file created by `save_file.php` is never created. Everything else that needs to happen (another temp file creation that doesn't require sudo + a database insert) work fine, but everything else is in `write_get` rather than in the `sudo-requiring save_file`.

I assume the server somehow blocks this call to `exec("sudo...`  when it's made remotely? Or if not, what's happening here? Most importantly, how can I work around this?

---

p.s. I understand there are probably major security concerns here, but please know there is no sensitive data/anything on this server and that the files created in the `sudo-requiring` script don't even contain user input, so for the moment I am more concerned with trying to do the above than with creating a safer file structure/alternate way of doing this.

Comment: Is the user that php and/or apache is using in the sudoers list and configured to be allowed to execute with no password?

Comment: easier to change the file permissions ?

Comment: @Dagon that latter is not an option.

Comment: @helloB You obviously have root access to the server. Why is changing the file permissions not an option? There has to be a safer alternative to using both `exec` and `sudo` in a PHP script. Also as Justin mentions above, the Apache user would need to have root access **without** a password, which means you are essentially executing Apache as root. All three of these open up gaping security holes. All it would take for a user to gain root access would be to upload a PHP file to your web server. I would strongly consider doing it another way, or you're just looking to get your server hacked.

Comment: @JustinPearce thanks for this suggestion. I didn't even know about the sudoers list so this must be the problem. However, now I have added www-data to the sudoers list and to no password, and I have also run sudo -k to restart, but I still have the same result.

Comment: @Mike if I want to create files in /var/www/html in response to user actions, clearly I don't want to change the file permissions of this root web directory. But I want the URL's created for these files to be at the very base of the domain name. So for example, user calls the script to create a file and then can go directly to example.com/file_just_created. I don't want to have complicated URL's, which is why I am resisting file permission based solutions.

Comment: Actually, it's not clear to me why you wouldn't want to change the permissions of /var/www/html to be writable by the www-data user. That seems way more sane to me than basically making www-data root.

Comment: @Mike I suppose I don't see the difference at that point, and sudo seems easier?

Comment: @helloB Just do `chown -R www-data:www:data /var/www/html` and don't worry about trying to make the Apache user sudo to root.

Comment: Also, when doing it this way you don't have to use `exec` either. Just include the other file from your main script.

Comment: @Mike Ok I'll go with your solution. Thanks a lot. If you write it as an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a bad idea because you would need to give paswordless root access to the Apache user, which is essentially like making the Apache user equal to root. All it would take to gain root access to your server would be to upload a malicious PHP script and have that script executed by the Apache user. Instead just make the files you are writing to writable by the Apache user by executing:

```
chown -R www-data:www:data /var/www/html
```

And then instead of doing `exec()` just `include` the other PHP file in your main script.